# Lodash memoize – How do i delete a cache entry that has a complex key?

Tags: javascript, caching, lodash, memoization

I have a lodash memoized function that uses a resolver function to generate the key...

```js
  const serializeArgs = (animal, eatsGrass) => animal + (eatsGrass? "#eatsGrass" : "") 
  const myMemoizedFunction = _.memoize( myFunction, serializeArgs )
```

The docs don't seem to say how i delete a cache entry for that. I'm assuming it's...

```js
  myMemoizedFunction.cache.delete(serializeArgs("horse", true))
```

Answer (score 1):

Did a few tests and *yes* that is how you do it. `Cache.delete()` seems to take a single string for an argument.